# How is difficulty used by mining clients?

Tags: mining, proof-of-work, difficulty

I understand how it's calculated and what its intent is. I'm unsure of how the value is being used in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short it increases/decreases the number of computations (time needed) to solve the proof-of-work puzzles to adjust the actual mining time to the target mining time.

Comment: Thanks for the input. For more specificity, check apendix J of the [yellow paper.](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf)